# How To Disable Pop Up Google Translation With HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, language-translation

I use Google Widget to Translate in my website . But when I Click Translate it will show pop up in Top my Page and Dissuade my Menu Navigation when scrolled down .

I was tried with some css, html and javascript but it cant fix 
how to hide google translation pop up from my Menu Navigation when it clicked ?

CSS :

```
#google_translate_element{width:300px;float:right;text-align:right;display:block}
#goog-gt-tt {dispaly:none;visibility: hidden;}
```

HTML And JavaScript :

```
<div class="google_translate_element" id="google_translate_element"></div><div 
id="goog-gt-tt" 
class="goog-tooltip skiptranslate"  ></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'id', includedLanguages: 'af,ar,de,en,eo,es,et,fa,fr,id,it,ja,jv,ka,kn,la,mn,ms,ne,nl,pa,ru,so,sr,su,ta,th,tl,tr,uk,vi,zh-CN,zh-TW', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: Can you try adding #goog-gt-tt {dispaly:none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}

Comment: @Nick Thanks , but It did fix

Comment: @Nick_O Thanks. I've noticed the ID for the popup has since changed to #gtx-trans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I find it by looking in Inspect Element . Just Make those all be Hide

```
#google_translate_element{width:300px;float:right;text-align:right;display:block}
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate { display: none !important;} 
body { top: 0px !important; }
#goog-gt-tt{display: none !important; top: 0px !important; } 
.goog-tooltip skiptranslate{display: none !important; top: 0px !important; } 
.activity-root { display: hide !important;} 
.status-message { display: hide !important;}
.started-activity-container { display: hide !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following URL, changing `.` for `-` from the website you want to translate and using the language code you wish (E.g: `en` for English):

> https://`url_here`.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=`from_lang`&_x_tr_tl=`to_lang`

For instance, if you want to translate the website `stackoverflow.com` from English to Catalan, you would use this URL:

> https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ca