# how to hide Google translator popup even if setting is done in brower side using html or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

how to hide Google translator popup  even if setting in brower side with language option enabled using html and css ?

```
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
body {
    top: 0px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Disable Pop Up Google Translation With HTML CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811427/how-to-disable-pop-up-google-translation-with-html-css)

Comment: but still its not hide

Comment: it will hide only by made changes in browser setting